# How to properly use Realm objects in a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to use Realm in my UITableViewController and I'm running into issues whenever I try to find the object at a row index if I cast the object to its class (forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm still pretty new to Swift, Realm ans iOS dev!)...

I have a `Site` class which looks like this, and the database has a few thousand entries:

```
class Site: RLMObject {
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
}
```

In my table view controller, when I try to fetch a `Site` based on its index in the result set to load into a cell, if I try to cast it to a `Site` object it's always nil! If I let it be set using `AnyObject`, then I can see that the correct site at that index has indeed been found.

I'm guessing the `.name` call on `AnyObject` is only working because `AnyObject` responds to `.name`, but it helps me to see that the index is correct and that the site does exist...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let allSites = Site.allObjects()
    var any: AnyObject = allSites.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row))
    var site = allSites.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? Site
    println("With AnyObject: \(any.name)")
    println("With casting: \(site?.name)")

    return cell
}
```

The result of the print statements above look like this (for example on a site which is named 'Addeboda'):

```
With AnyObject: Addeboda
With casting: Optional("")
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've googled around a bit, and all the tutorials and answers I can find along similar lines suggest that `results.objectAtIndex(index) as Class` should be the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No cast needed

It seems that casting to Site is not needed. This works fine:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let allSites = Site.allObjects()
    let site: AnyObject! = allSites[UInt(indexPath.row)]

    cell.textLabel!.text = site.name

    println("Site is: \(site.id)")

    return cell
}
```

Seems to be a bug with either Swift or Realm. I'm guessing one of them gets confused when downcasting `AnyObject!` to something.

### Initializing a new instance with correct type

However, if you really need to use the `Site` model class you can initialize a new `RLMObject` from the result:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let allSites = Site.allObjects()
    let site = Site(object: allSites[UInt(indexPath.row)])

    cell.textLabel!.text = site.name

    println("Site is: \(site.id)")

    return cell
}
```

### First try

It is unfortunate to hear that you are having issues with Realm and Swift. I am by no means a Swift pro, but it looks like you are casting `site` to an optional, and the result of using the optional cast operator `site?.name` is also an optional. Hence getting `Optional("")`.

Can you try to see if you have any better luck with the following?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let allSites = Site.allObjects()

    if var site = allSites[UInt(indexPath.row)] as? Site {
        println("Site is: \(site.name)")
    } else {
        println("it not castable to Site. It is: \(toString(allSites[UInt(indexPath.row)].dynamicType))")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Also, you can use `yourObject.dynamicType` to get a reference to the objects real class type.

Best of luck

Comment: It raises an exception while trying to unwrap an optional value when you call `site.name` the first time.

Comment: Excellent, `Site(object: allSites[UInt(indexPath.row)])` worked! It does need to be cast, though. It is just by chance that `AnyObject` has a `name` function which made `site.name` work. Trying to use `site.id` raised an exception on `AnyObject`..

Comment: Are you sure? When I had `var site: AnyObject! = ...` and had renamed the properties to `lolId` and `lolName` that method still worked...

Comment: Yeah, it made the build fail and said "'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'id'"

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code from the [tableview sample project](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/TableView/TableViewController.swift):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var array = DemoObject.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("date", ascending: true)
    ...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell

        let object = array[UInt(indexPath.row)] as DemoObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description

        return cell
    }
}
```

You should be able to cast on the line you are storing that indexPath.row object